# How do I upgrade my graphics on my laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, graphics-card, amd-radeon, integrated-graphics

I recently bought an [HP dv6 6180us](http://www.frys.com/product/6895236) laptop. The [PDF datasheet](http://media.webcollage.net/rwvfp/wc/live/7969505/module/hpeasset/edge.services.sellpath.com/Renderer/http@co/c242173.r73.cf3.rackcdn.com/HP-2216382-HP4f58ddf1225bc.pdf/index.pdf) says that I have a Radeon HD 6770M switchable graphics card with 1024 MB of GDDR5 RAM and up to 4096 MB total graphics memory.

How am I able to upgrade it to 4096 MB? Do I need to buy something, and if I do, can you please provide a link to what I need? I am already going to upgrade to [16 GB of RAM](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Pavilion%20dv6-6180us&Cat=RAM).

Also, is it worth it to upgrade to 4096 MB? I'm about to study computer science if that helps at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading the graphics on a laptop is generally not possible. The graphics is embedded directly as part of the laptop motherboard. The "switchable" indicates that the operating system is able to intelligently "switch" between the Radeon and another integrated graphics on the CPU, based on the need of the application being used.

Also changing the graphics memory is not really necessary (or possible). Graphics memory is generally used for gaming, particularly at very high resolutions. The extra memory is helpful to store large game scene textures and effects.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I don't need to buy anything to get 4096 mb right? It basically does it by itself meaning I don't need to configure anything?

Comment: What I'm saying is YOU CANNOT. The amount is fixed.

Comment: Sorry I'm asking such nooby questions. So do I have 1024 or 4096 right now?

Comment: It says "up to" because the graphics memory is reallocated from your RAM. That's how integrated graphics work on a computer. It will allocate however much it needs, up to 4 GB, out of the 6 GB of RAM that you have, total.

Comment: @sidran32 Ok so if I am normally just browsing the internet then the amount of graphics memory being used is normal, but then if all of a sudden I decide to play battlefield, then the graphics memory automatically goes up, Correct?

Comment: @Backtrack I believe in switchable graphics, that's how it will operate. In my experience, with just standard integrated graphics, it keeps the amount of memory allocated to graphics operations constant. However, with switchable graphics, it seems that it will reallocate more when using the ATI graphics, as opposed to the integrated Intel graphics.